# Change C# compile directory (Class Library & WPF; not ASP.NET)?

Tags: c#, performance, compiler-construction, tempdir

I'm running a Ramdisk in Windows 7.  I've modified some web.config files to noticeably improve the compilation times of my ASP.NET solutions.

I've got a solution with about 40 WPF and Class Library projects, and it hasn't improved when I launch Visual Studio in an environment whose TEMP/TMP are pointed to the Ramdisk.

So, I'm thinking these TEMP/TMP environment variables don't influence the temp folders used when C# is compiling WPF and Class Library projects.

Can I change the temp folder C# uses when compiling WPF and Class Library projects?

Comment: wow I was using ramdisk to improve compile time at the age of clipper, about 25 years ago, never know that tricks are used still today :)

Comment: I'm experimenting and may find there's no advantage to the Ramdisk.  I had great (very noticeable) speed improvement a year ago, but that was WinXP and exclusively ASP.NET solutions.

Comment: Did my answer help? If so, how much?

Comment: It helped me confirm that the compilation I/O was happening on the Ramdisk, where my project files were.  After several comparisons, I found the Ramdisk to not offer any appreciable speed increase when compiling or running tests (though, Find in Files was instant, which was nice!).  I've uninstalled the Ramdisk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# doesn't use a temp folder when compiling normal projects.

The ASP.Net runtime uses a temp folder to store the  `.cs` files generated by ASPX pages before passing them to `csc.exe`, but normal projects are compiled in-place.

You can move the intermediary `obj` folder by [changing the `BaseIntermediateOutputPath` property in the `.csproj` file](http://geekswithblogs.net/jolson/archive/2006/03/11/72061.aspx), which may help.